# Definition of mechanical impedance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, vibrations

[Mechanical impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_impedance) is in the simplest (yet common) case defined as:

$$
Z_m = \frac{F}{v}
$$

where $F$ is force (let's assume 1D case) and $v$ velocity of the object (let's assume point of mass).

**Now, should the force be sum of forces applied on the point of mass or just the force of excitation?**

**An example to clarify.** Undamped linear harmonic oscillator driven by the force $F$ of angular frequency $\Omega$:

$$
\ddot{x}+\omega^2x^2 = \frac{F_e}{m}e^{i\Omega t}
$$

If there is no initial velocity or displacement, the velocity is simply:

$$
v = \frac{F_e}{m}\frac{i\Omega}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}e^{i\Omega t}
$$

Therefore for mechanical impedance:

$$
Z_m = \frac{F}{v} = \frac{F_e e^{i\Omega t}}{\frac{F_e}{m}\frac{i\Omega}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}e^{i\Omega t}} = \frac{F_e}{\frac{F_e}{m}\frac{i\Omega}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}} = -im\frac{\omega^2-\Omega^2}{\Omega} = -i\left(\frac{k}{\Omega}-m\Omega\right)
$$

where $k$ denotes stiffness as usual.

**OR**

Should the force be sum of the all forces in the system:

$$
F = F_e e^{i\Omega t} - kx = -\frac{\Omega^2}{\omega^2-\Omega^2} F_ee^{i\Omega t}
$$

and therefore:

$$
Z_m = im\Omega
$$

Maybe I have a mistake somewhere but in the latter case the $k$ vanishes which I find really suspicious...

Comment: it should be sum of all forces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force  and http://www.bksv.com/doc/17-179.pdf

Comment: I edited your formula for Zm (correct one), units should be kg/s or m*omega

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I don't follow - you've said, that it should be sum of all forces but in the links small omega doen't vanish which implies only exciting force to be calculated.

Comment: oh, sorry. my very bad. I was thinking about summation of impedances of two elements. Of course there is only one force acting upon oscillator, the $F$ force! You should use it and only it

Comment: External force converts into law of motion via $F_{ext}=ma+kx$, there are no additional forces but $F_{ext}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition you should use total force on the system. In this case total force acting upon system is load, F. What $mx''+kx$ is, a response of the system, not some random force from nowhere, it is just Newton's law.

By intuition it looks like that. There is an impedance due to the spring and there is an impedance due to the mass at the end of the spring. They are separate and independent phenomena. Total impedance equals sum of impedances of serially connected elements in mechanics, same way as impedance of electrical circuit is a sum for serially connected elements.